# Send Cyrillic text through Socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, unicode

I have problem with sending Cyrillic text "УБА221" via C# socket. It turned to "#xxxxx221". Here is xxxxx are 5 strange alphabets I can't copy paste.

**Server side(receiving side):**

```
SocketPacket theSockId = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
int iRx = theSockId.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
int charLen = d.GetChars(theSockId.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
TextLabel.Text =TextLabel.Text+ szData;
```

**Client side(sending):**

```
subtext = "УБА221";
byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(subtext);
socket.Send(byData);
```

Is there any idea why my code is not working?

Comment: I changed UTF32 to UTF8. But still not working. I'm going to try Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesToDecode) later.

Answer (score 2):

Look at how you're encoding the text to send it:

```
byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(subtext);
```

Now look at how you're decoding the binary data back into text:

```
System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
```

You're using UTF-32 to encode, and UTF-8 to decode. That's not going to work. You need to use the same encoding on both sides.

Also note:

- There's no guarantee that you'll have received the whole text in a single `BeginReceive/EndReceive` call
- If you *do* just want to decode a single byte array, use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesToDecode)` rather than going via `Decoder`.
- If you want to handle the situation where you get part of a character in one read call and then part in another read, you *will* want to use `Decoder`, but you'll need to preserve the `Decoder` between read calls, as that stores the state of "not yet decoded data".

Comment: I'm getting 1 char per socket reading cycle. Above receiving code is inside OnDataReceived. How can I read whole string?

Comment: @user3145861: Well we don't know what your receive call looks like - please include that in the question. You won't be able to assume you'll read the whole string in one go, mind you - that's not the way streaming protocols work. (We also don't know what higher level protocol you're using - do you want to just keep reading until the other side closes the socket, or do you have something to indicate when the message has finished?)